# iOS Export as Ad Hoc Error: Failed to locate or generate signing assets

Tags: ios, xcode

Since I have updated Xcode to version 6.0.1, I can't export app as Ad Hoc. I had tried many solutions, but they were useless. I have reassigned my certificate and provisioning profile as well. But it was without any success.I have no idea what to do... Maybe anyone had same thing before as I have now?

Error details:
[image: Error detais]
Profile details:
[image: profile]
Build settings:
[image: build 1]
[image: Build 2]
P.S. It is not duplicate theme. I have tried all solutions from questions like this... They all doesn't work for me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I have found solution to my problem. You have to be iOS Distributor (iOS Developer is not enough) to export application for Ad Hoc deployment.

Comment: In simple words, create distribution certificates instead of development.